# How do i add Aitken Sequence in my root finding algorithm

Tags: python, numeric, numerical-methods

```
from numpy import log as ln                 
def g(x):
    return ln(4+x-x**2)

def FixedPoint(p0,tolerance):                     
    p = g(p0)                                
    abs_error = abs(p-p0)                    
    p0 = p                          
    while abs_error>=tolerance:                 
        p = g(p0)                                
        abs_error = abs(p-p0)                    
        p0 = p                                   
    return p

starting_point = 2
tolerance = 10**-10
fixed_point = FixedPoint(starting_point,tolerance)

print('Fixed-point of g(x) = {0} is x = {1:.7f}'.format(formula,fixed_point))
```

So, i have this fixed point root finding algorithm to find the root of ln(4+x-x^2), how do i add the aitken sequence program to increase the rate of convergence of finding the root of ln(4+x-x^2). im having trouble in keeping the value of each iterations.

Comment: I hope you are solving `exp(x)=4+x-x^2`. What did you already try for Aitken's delta squared process? It could look similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3109837/115115

Answer (score 1):

I would reduce the number of lines in the fixed-point iteration via

```py
def FixedPoint(p0,tolerance):                     
    p1 = g(p0)                                
    while abs(p1-p0)>=tolerance:                 
        p0,p1 = p1,g(p1) 
        print(p0)                               
    return p1
```

This requires 29 evaluations of `g` for the given test case

The Aitken delta-squared process can be implemented as

```py
def FixedPointAitken(p0,tolerance):                     
    while True:                 
        p1=g(p0); p2=g(p1);   
        print(p0,p1,p2)
        if abs(p1-p0)<tolerance: break
        p0 = p0 - (p1-p0)**2/(p0+p2-2*p1) 
    return p0
```

This requires 5 steps with 15 evaluations of `g` to reach the target accuracy.